# Android media player play and pause not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I create a Android App. when i press play, it will play and when i press it again it will pause. but when i press stop then press play again, it will not play anymore.

this is my java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.top);

        Button btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.pause();
                }else{
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
        Button btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Mediaplayer documentation, especially at its states:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

When you call stop(), you go to state Stopped. In order to use start(), you should go to Prepared state by calling prepare() either synchronously or asynchronously.